# 403 Forbidden Error - Jupyter Server on Anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

By mistake I rebooted my system with open Notebooks in Firefox browser. Ever since I cannot get a Jupyter Server running properly from my Anaconda.

As expected, I can get to the base folder on my system but as soon as I click to open a new folder or notebook the server throws the error `Server error: Forbidden` at me.

The error seems to be related to login cookies:

```
[I 08:16:34.286 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=1aed47898bede70ff7f27f2518660b343cd64995372d9d58 (127.0.0.1) 0.000000ms
C:\Users\sb123\.conda\envs\Thesis2\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\base\handlers.py:240: UserWarning: The Tornado web application does not have an 'identity_provider' defined in its settings. In future releases of jupyter_server, this will be a required key for all subclasses of `JupyterHandler`. For an example, see the jupyter_server source code for how to add an identity provider to the tornado settings: https://github.com/jupyter-server/jupyter_server/blob/aa8fd8b3faf37466eeb99689d5555314c5bf6640/jupyter_server/serverapp.py#L253
  warnings.warn(
[E 08:16:34.650 NotebookApp] Error unpacking user from cookie: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
[W 08:16:34.650 NotebookApp] Clearing invalid/expired login cookie username-127-0-0-1-8890
[I 08:16:34.651 NotebookApp] 302 GET /server-proxy/servers-info (127.0.0.1) 3.000000ms
[W 08:16:36.070 NotebookApp] Forbidden
[W 08:16:36.070 NotebookApp] 403 GET /api/contents/Documents?type=directory&_=1673594194483 (127.0.0.1) 1.000000ms referer=http://127.0.0.1:8890/tree/Documents
```

The error can be reproduced across webbrowsers (I tried Firefox and Edge).

When I launch the server from within Pycharm Pro however, I can open, edit and run notebooks without a problem, both in the IDE as well as in Firefox.

I did not find any hints on the web and would be grateful for your support.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to clean you browser cache? Have you tried to run Jupyter as administrator?

Comment: Hi @ggeop, I have tried clearing the Firefox cache. As said, the same problem came up when opening the Jupyter URL in Edge. I have also launched an Anaconda Powershell as Admin and launched `Jupyter Notebook` and the same error appears...

Comment: Hi @ggeop I have now created a test environment and re-installed Python and Jupyter. I can open and execute notebooks without a problem. My current environment is quite extensive and it seems as I may need to re-create it as a new environment although I would have preferred to get it back up and running.

Answer (score 12):

I have exactly the same problem (in a pip venv).

For me, `pip install --upgrade 'jupyter-server<2.0.0'` did the trick for the time being. This is obviously not a "solution", but so far I have no idea how to find out what is wrong.

I am a single user on a local maching - it seems it has something to do with security. I don't want to deal with complicated login methods. Token based is absolutely sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

No further understanding of the issue here, but I solved it by uninstalling everything Jupyter-related and then installing Jupyter notebooks. **Only reinstalling `notebook` did not help**.

In my case, I used conda

```bash
conda uninstall notebook
conda list | grep jupyter
# conda or pip uninstall anything left
conda install notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

For, command from [Raubtier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221670/11671779) is not working. I use this instead,

```bash
pip install jupyter-server==1.24.0
```

Also, removing jupyterlab might help, since old jupyter-server is intended for old but gold classic jupyter notebook.